# when update composer guzzle abandoned error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, guzzle

When composer update this error occur

```
Package guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. 
Use guzzlehttp/guzzle instead.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: in your composer.json just change guzzle/guzzle with the one it mentions thats all since the first one is abondoned (if you dont find it that means another package is using it)

Comment: "require": {
  "laravel/socialite" : "2.0.20",
  "oriceon/oauth-5-laravel": "dev-master",
  "laravel/framework": "5.0.16",
  "league/oauth2-client": "0.10.1",
        "vimeo/vimeo-api": "1.1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
  "google/apiclient": "^2.1"
 },

Comment: thanks for reply. this is composer.json require.. i am using guzzlehttp/guzzle package but error is guuzle/guzzle package

Comment: One of the packages you're using probably uses Guzzle internally. I'd update them - Laravel is up to 5.4 now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this message is not an error

Try

`composer update`

```
composer why guzzle/guzzle
```

Answer (score 18):

If there is a package installed that you did not require explicitly, you can use the `why-not` command of Composer to check why this package was installed:

```
composer why guzzle/guzzle
```

Comment: And be aware that this message is not an error but an suggestion! This notice does not mean your project doesn't run anymore.